# Array of colors as props and build multiple nested frames

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[RainbowFrame component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDnbb.png)

Help do that, pls.

The RainbowFrame component should receive an array of colors as props and build multiple nested frames, one for each color (in any order). Inside the frames should be the content that is nested in the RainbowFrame tag.

How can implement this component, at least in native JS. Not necessarily in React.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index.jsx

```
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import RainbowFrame from "../../components/RainbowFrame";

const Rainbow = () => {

  const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue', 'green', 'gray'];

  return (
    <Box
      id='container'
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <RainbowFrame colors={colors}>
        <b>TEXT</b>
      </RainbowFrame>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Rainbow;
```

RainbowFrame.jsx

```
const RainbowFrame = ({ colors, children }) => {

  let currentContent = null;

  colors.map((color, index) => {
    const content = colors[index - 1] ? currentContent : children;

    return currentContent = <div style={{ border: `5px solid ${color}`, padding: '10px' }}>{content}</div> 
  })

  return currentContent;
}

export default RainbowFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is run the .map() on array and make it return the component for each element of the array. Try checking out the mapping with react!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).